# Using python to calculate how much tax one needs to pay in HK

Tags: python

So the task is to code a program on python to calculate salary tax - using method 1 - progressive rate, and method 2 - standard rate.

In other words: How much I should pay if I earn HKD$240,000 each year using both methods? Which one is a better method?

[Reference on tax calculation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K885G.png)

Here is my code, I am not sure why when I input an integer, it returns me with the 'not a number!' statement instead of the if-condition I am expecting.

```
def progressiveRate(income):
    rate=0.02
    result=0
    while (income>0):
        if (income>50000):
            result += 50000 * rate
            rate += 0.04
        else:
            result += income * 0.17
        income -= 50000
    return result

income = input('Input your income')
if (income.isdigit()):
    income = int(income)
    print(progressiveRate(income))
else:
    print("Not a number!")
```

Comment: Your code is invalid. It needs correct indentation.

Comment: It seems to be missing a `def progressiveRate(income):` line or more

Comment: change to `income = int(input('Input your income'))` to avoid `'not a number!'` error, `income = int(income)` is not needed

Answer (score 0):

The input is read as string. So you have to explicitly convert to int

```py
income = int(input('Input your income'))
```

This should solve the issue

Comment: But then, another issue occurs. It says
"'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'". Not quite sure what it means ..

Comment: In the above code income is already in 'int' as I am converting it before assigning, and yes 'int' has no method isdigit(), isdigit is part of string methods. You could rather change your code to this:
```python
try:
    income = int(input('Input your income'))
    print(progressiveRate(income))
except:
    print("Not a number!")
```